# How to set the execution directory with JCreator (Pro)?

Tags: java, jcreator

Is it possible, to execute a class in a specified directory?

I mean, a.class is in directory abc and i want it to be executed as if it were in directory xyz (directly from the IDE of JCreator).

Comment: Was it the environment setting or the shortcut path that worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't that in the runtime environment settings? If not I'd try making a shortcut that runs the full path of JCreator but set the the current directory to where you want the execution to happen.