# Replace java code with custom shorter words

Tags: java

Is there a way to replace some code with custom (shorter) words?

Example: I don't want to type the words below all the time, but I want to type a shorter word. The /*compiler*/ pre-processor will replace my custom words with the originals.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}
```

I want to write something like this instead:

```
protected void doGet(banana, apple) foo, bar {
    processRequest(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Create your own language called "Fruits" where every keyword is a fruit! :) More seriously, that's the class name, nothing you can do. But note that in a IDE, typing `HttpSer` + Ctrl Space will list you both classes as 1st and 2nd choice.

Comment: Haha yea, would be nice. But is there a way to do this is java? Some mapping between words or something?
I use autocomplete, but I type faster than my autocomplete can auto complete :)

Comment: Use an IDE with code completion so that you don't have to type the complete words all the time.

Comment: Compilers don't do that.

Comment: Hopefully, you don't get to type `InternalFrameInternalFrameTitlePaneInternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonWindowNotFocusedState` too often.

Comment: :) Nope. But like my example shorter words would be nice for my laziness.

Comment: Maybe your IDE could perform a macro that does find&replace for you?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202223/auto-code-completion-on-eclipse

Comment: But how would you remember which fruit is a request and which one is the response? :)

Comment: There would be a list in a file with something like this: banana = HttpServletRequest request; apple = HttpServletResponse response; ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a job for a pre-processor not a compiler. Unfortunately for you Java doesn't have a pre-processor. If you were using a language with one you could simply use `#define` statements.

For a few cases you can use `static final` if the thing you want to shorten can be saved as a variable E.G. strings. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927107/define-in-java) question for more detail.

Otherwise your best bet is to download an IDE (E.G. IntelliJ or Eclipse) with code completion. you'll only need to type the first few letters and your IDE will complete the rest!

Edit: I see from your comment on @AlexWien's answer that  your computer is too slow to keep up with your typing in an IDE. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643346/what-is-a-good-ide-for-java-programming-on-a-low-end-laptop) answer for possible  solutions for your machine.

Another possible solution is simply writing the word youwant to use as a shortcut if you've got a sharp memory (or you could store the info on a bit of paper/notepad file). When you get to when you want to compile you could replace all instances of your shortcut using *find and replace*, probably only a solution for a few certain use cases.

Comment: cc is fast enough, but his laptop not.

Comment: True for both. cc is fast if my laptop would be faster. And for a good cc you have to type half the word sometimes. Would be much better to have a list with words that the IDE will auto replace when starting the program.

Comment: FORTUNATLEY:  Java doesn't have a pre-processor

Answer (score 2):

To help to reduce your typing work, is not the job of the compiler.
It is the job of the IDE, like Eclipse.
Just type the first 3 letters, and then Ctrl-Space, the IDE shows then a list of suitable names.

That way you have the best of both: few typing and long meaningful and hopefully self-explaining names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use Eclipse, but my cheap laptop is often not fast enough for the autocomplete. So I end up typing it anyway.

Comment: if eclipse is slow, try to use two generations older versions of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace the name of a class with something else, but if you have a long method, you could in some situations wrap it in another one like this:

```
void banana() {
    insanelyLongMethodName();
}

banana();
```

Comment: @Gendarme You could replace the name of the class in a similar way using `extends`. Then do what you suggest with the methods, adding `super` to each one.

Comment: @Knells extending HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, ServletException, and IOException is possible I suppose. But I assumed it would be much more pain than gain doing that.

But you are correct.

Comment: Just my opinion, but altering program structure to save typing seems like misaligned priorities...

Answer (score 1):

There is also some other JVM languages, as Kotlin, that you can try with less boilerplate. See https://kotlinlang.org/